# Как выделить все нужные файлы для гита? VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuex

Раньше работал с Java и при средних проектах делал команду git add или вручную выделял классы и пушил. Вот с Vue js думаю как сделать потому что тут помимо папки src где наши assets, components, router и тд еще есть и такие файлы как:

```
.babelrc
.editorconfig
.eslintignore
.gitignore
.postcssrc.js
.index.html
.package.json и т.д.
```

Существует такая команда чтобы всё нужное закинуть в Гит и чтобы не было проблем? 
 Понятно что ГитИгнор стоит и ничего лишнего аля модулей в гит не улетит. Либо подскажите как удобнее всего сделать или всё-таки вручную каждый файлик нужный делать git add, а если я изучаю Vue и знаю внешнее, а не прям каждый файлик, тогда что сделать?

Comment: Они все нужны, коммитьте их. `git add -A` и вперёд `git commit -m "commit description"`

Comment: @AK получается это git add all, но тогда выделится к примеру такая папка как .idea, а она мне не нужна

Comment: @AK Увидел в гитигноре .idea, получается если я сделаю команду git add -A, то я добавлю всё что мне нужно, а гитИгнор поможет не запушить лишнего?

Comment: Разумеется. В вашем .gitignore ещё и node_modules перечислен, так что попадёт только то, что нужно.

Comment: @AK спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все нужные файлы для git'а выделяются через команду

```
git add -A
```

Эта команда работает с учётом содержимого файла `.gitignore`

Поскольку вы работаете с каким-то автоматическим генератором, который создал boilerplate проекта с всеми этими перечисленными файлами (например, дали команду `vue init webpack`), то этот генератор создал и файл .gitignore с нужными исключениями.

Например, тот же vue init создаёт исключения для наиболее популярных редакторов кода (idea, vscode) и исключает служебные файлы и кталоги (лог-файлы, node_modules и т.п.):

```
.DS_Store
node_modules/
/dist/
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
```

Вы можете всегда поправить этот файл и закоммитить в него изменения (если это нужно всем участникам проекта), либо использовать свой локальный игнор-лист в `.git\info\exclude`.